# Binding select option to user id

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of tasks where a button can be clicked to show options for each task. One option  in the popup is to assign a user to the task. How can you preselect the user if there is one assigned? Here is the relevant code:

```
p Assign-to:
select ng-model="user" ng-change="assignUser(task, user)" ng-options="user.id as user.firstName for user in users"
  option value="" -- assign a user --
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to set the selected value by using the method you have, but this one works for me:

```
<select id="{{model.id}}" ng-model="model.answer">
  <option ng-repeat="item in model.options" value="{{item.value}}" 
          ng-selected="{{item.value == model.defaultvalue}}"
  >{{item.description}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

### ng-change do not work on select

You can refer that here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

### According to [Adam Zuckerman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/848058/adam-zuckerman)'s answer:

```
<select ng-model="selectedUser">
    <option value="">-- assign a user --</option>
    <option ng-repeat="user in users" value="{{user}}" 
            ng-selected="{{selectedUser.id === user.id}}">
        {{user.firstName}}
    </option>
</select>
```

this is a easier way to do this

### Other approach, use `ng-options`:

First, you need to understand a javascript language concept:

```
a = b = {}
a === b // true
```

by assign to refer same object, they will equal. But:

```
a = {}
b = {}
a === b // false
```

by assign to object value respectively, they will not equal.

So, if you want to bind your model (selected user) and default option value, you must to this:

```
$scope.users = [.....]
$scope.selectedUser = $scope.users[1] // assign refer to second object
```

and then:

```
<select ng-model="selectedUser" ng-options="user as user.firstName for user in users">
    <option value="">-- assign a user --</option>
</select>
```

#### refer to same object will work fine.